# Launch instances of same coroutine one after the other

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a scenario where I have multiple URLs to download PDFs. I need to make a network call for each url, process the pdf, send it to a printer, wait for the printer to finish and then continue with the next url. Im trying to get my head around coroutines but I cant understand how to apply it here.

Here I'm making a call for each url in an array and making a call, in the callback I call the method "printImage" where I send the pdf to a printer and I can listen for it to finish, how could I implement coroutines here? In this case the method "printImage" should be a coroutine

```
fun printLabels(labels: HashMap<Long, String>) {
    for (item in labels.values) {
        val call = labelService.getPDF(item)
        call.enqueue(
            object : retrofit2.Callback<ResponseBody> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {

                    val outputDir = cacheDir
                    val outputFile = File.createTempFile("prefix", "extension", outputDir)
                    Files.asByteSink(outputFile).write(response.body()!!.bytes())

                    val bitmap = getBitmap(outputFile)!!

                    printImage(bitmap)
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
                    Timber.e(t.localizedMessage)
                }

            }
        )
    }
}


  fun printImage(bm: Bitmap) {
    Thread(Runnable {
        printerRepository.currentPrinter.value?.let { printer ->
            if (printer.startCommunication()) {
                val result = printer.printImage(bm)
                if (result.errorCode != PrinterInfo.ErrorCode.ERROR_NONE) {
                    Timber.d("ERROR - " + result.errorCode)
                } else {

                }
                printer.endCommunication()
            } else {
                printerRepository.printerTestPassed.postValue(false)
            }
        }
    }).start()
}
```

Comment: Coroutines are for parallel programming. You described your task as strictly sequential. Why do you want to use coroutines? Why don't you program your task in a straightforward way, as a loop over the set or URLs?

Comment: But right now in your code your are not processing pdfs sequentially. You are processing them all at once. Is it right?

Comment: "I need to make a network call for each URL, process the pdf, send it to a printer, wait for the printer to finish and then continue with the next URL", does it really needs to be this way? I mean we can achieve better with asynchronicity.